# Looping through columns using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to loop through columns to replace its values.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

In this example, I want to replace the decimal comma of the first two columns with decimal points.

When trying to use a *for* loop like

```
for col in opel_Df[['Altitude Variation', 'Vehicle Speed Instantaneous']]:
    opel_Df[col] = opel_Df[col].replace(',', '.')
```

nothing happens, but this is because I have to set `inplace=True`, but when I do so, I get `none` values:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
col = ['Altitude Variation', 'Vehicle Speed Instantaneous']

opel_Df[col] = opel_Df[col].replace(',', '\.', regex=True)
```